# Create Keyboard Shortcut?

Tags: python

I am searching for a way to create a cross-platform keyboard shortcut in Python. Such that when I press something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, the program will run a certain function.

Does there exist such method or library?

Comment: might be an overly simplistic question, but are you talking about creating keyboard shortcuts during code editing or shortcuts for users to interact with your program?

Comment: @MattR Shortcuts for users to interact with the program. For example, a user clicks "Ctrl + F" and I run a set of commands or functions instantly.

Comment: I'd look into creating a shortcut when Terminal/CMD/ or to your OS and then bind it to a script.py, something like: https://superuser.com/questions/333758/bind-a-hotkey-combination-to-command-prompt. What you are asking for is not really the "way" of doing things if I think.

Comment: This isn't easy to make truly cross-platform in the terminal, but it's fairly straight-forward if you do it in a GUI with a cross-platform GUI library; even Tkinter can do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try `keyboard`. It can be installed with `pip install keyboard`, and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> example can be accomplished with the syntax:

```
import keyboard
keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl + c", print, args=("Hello", "world!"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know is it possible to send combinations of Ctrl and/or alt. I tried couple of times but I think it doesn't work. (If someone has any other information please correct me). What you can do is something like this:

```
from msvcrt import getch

while True:
    key = ord(getch())
    if key == 27: #ESC
        PrintSomething()

def PrintSomething():
    print('Printing something')
```

this will run a scrpit every time you press ESC although it will only work when you run it in command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a listener for keypress event by `pynput` library.
this is a simple code that run a function when press `CTRL+ALT+H` keys:

```py
from pynput import keyboard

def on_activate():
    print('Global hotkey activated!')

def for_canonical(f):
    return lambda k: f(l.canonical(k))

hotkey = keyboard.HotKey(
    keyboard.HotKey.parse('<ctrl>+<alt>+h'),
    on_activate)
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=for_canonical(hotkey.press),
        on_release=for_canonical(hotkey.release)) as l:
    l.join()
```